# How to delete frame without deleting children in Figma?

Tags: figma

This is a pretty simple question, but how do I delete a frame without deleting all its contents in Figma? Is this possible and/or advisable?

I know I can drag all the contents out of the frame, but that seems inefficient.

Example:
Delete "Home" without deleting "Rectangle 1".

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A frame is just a special kind of group. Ungrouping will remove the frame and leave its content. To do it, select the frame in the layers panel, or select it in the main window, and from the menu do *Object > Ungroup Selection*, or use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

After doing so, you may want to goup the objects as an ordinary group <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, so that you can move or reposition them all together without changing the layout.